# Flask python app.py doesn't run but manage.py runserver does

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, circular-dependency

I have a flask app which I am trying to run. It seems when I run python app.py, there is a circular import of some sort. Here is the code for both my models.py and app.py:

**models.py**

```
import datetime
from app import bcrypt, db

class User(BaseModel, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    registered_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)

    def __init__(self, email, password, admin=False):
        self.email = email
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password)
        self.registered_on = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.admin = admin
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask import request, jsonify, session
from flask.ext.bcrypt import Bcrypt

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from models import User

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy()

POSTGRES = {
    'user': 'postgres',
    'db': 'postgres',
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': '5432',
}
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://%(user)s@%(host)s:%(port)s/%(db)s' % POSTGRES
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'lol'

bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)

db.init_app(app)

@app.route('/api/register', methods=['POST'])
def register():
    json_data = request.json
    user = User(
        email=json_data['email'],
        password=json_data['password']
    )
    try:
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        status = 'success'
    except:
        status = 'this user is already registered'
    db.session.close()
    return jsonify({'result': status})
```

**manage.py**

```
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from app import app, db
from models import User

migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)

manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

@manager.command
def create_admin():
    """Creates the admin user."""
    db.session.add(User(email='admin@admin.com', password='admin', admin=True))
    db.session.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

I have played around with the imports but nothing seems to work, I usually will get a circular import error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 7, in <module>
    from models import User
  File "/Users/Rishub/Desktop/apps/topten/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app import bcrypt, db
  File "/Users/Rishub/Desktop/apps/topten/app.py", line 7, in <module>
    from models import User
ImportError: cannot import name User
```

Does anyone know the solution to this? 
In addition, if I run python manage.py runserver, my app runs fine so I am curious as to why this works but python app.py does not.

Comment: share `manage.py` code so we can say how that is running and not `app.py`. My guess is that manage.py is not connected to app.py hence it's working.

Comment: just added manage.py

Comment: I have no clue how your manage.py is working. but you need to restructure your code as the link I shared says. Do that and app.py should get fixed.

Comment: could u answer my question below? thanks

Comment: Python app.py does not work because you don't run the instance, like manager, you need to call the run() method of the instance. Try adding app.run() at the end of app.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in models.py you are importing:

```
from app import bcrypt, db
```

in app.py you are importing models.

```
from models import User
```

To fix it restructure the program as shown here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/sqlalchemy/

create a database.py file with database configs etc.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:////tmp/test.db', convert_unicode=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

def init_db():
    import models
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

use this in models.py as

```
from database import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

# instead of db.column directly use Column

class User(Base):
```

and app files as:

```
from database import init_db
init_db()
from database import db_session
from models import User

@app.route('/api/register', methods=['POST'])
def register():
    json_data = request.json
    user = User(
        email=json_data['email'],
        password=json_data['password']
    )
    db_session.add(user)
    db_session.commit()
    return jsonify({'result': 'success'})
```

Comment: I have a class BaseModel(db.Model): but without db, how do I do this?

Comment: added the code piece you should use for `class User(Base):`

Comment: is there no actual app instance like "app = Flask(__name__)"? I am still confused how I would use bcrypt like I did above

Comment: you can still use it right? `app = Flask(__name__)` `bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)`. what's wrong with doing this?